# How to Remove Telegram Bot description?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

**How Can I Remove Telegram Bot description?**

I mean First Time I Added `/setdescription`
And in my Bot Main Page I Got: **What Can This Bot do?**

How Can I Remove `What Can This Bot do?` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe by sending a space.

If this doesn't work you probably can't delete it. So either leave it or set a . or a -

Comment: That's Very Bad. I Couldn't Solve With Space, Maybe in Future That will Be Solve.

Comment: yeah that sucks. but the telegram bot api also does not say anything about it. an the botfather does just have the option to set, so to update, and not to delete

Answer (score 0):

There is still no convenient way to remove telegram bot description in 2023, but there is one dangerous, inconvenient and "not for everyone" way - you can delete your bot through BotFather and recreate it with the same username. **USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK** - if you have any current users of your bot they will not be able to send messages, chat with the bot become "Deleted Account" for them and they will have to re-enter to your bot through search or direct link and start again with `/start` command. And of course your will have to change bot token in your environment, set bot picture again, webhook etc. So **this method mostly acceptable only for bots in development stage** with no (or small amount) of real users.